# Can't use self signed certificates any more, because "Enable full trust for root certificates" is gone from settings

Tags: ios, settings, certificate

[image: This is what the menu shows for me]

As you can see, "Enable full trust for root certificates" is completely missing. What do I do?

This is on iPhone X 11.4 btw.

Comment: "In iOS 10.3 and later, when you manually install a profile that contains a certificate payload, that certificate isn't automatically trusted for SSL. " taken from https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204477. So you need first to install the Profile containing the Certificate (which need to be a CA)

Comment: @CamilleG. how might one go about doing what you have suggested?

Comment: @adam The easiest way to do it is to send the CA Certificate by email and open the email on your iOS device.